# displaying an icon in the notification bar for a windows service?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, service, notifications, icons

i am using the code from this website to create a basic service
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppWindowsService-cacf4948

and i want this service to appear as an icon in the toolbar.
would i be able to start and stop the service from the icon?

right now i have to go into the SCM to start and stop the service and it takes too long to scroll down the list and find the service then start or stop it.

some websites are saying this can't be done because you can't interact with a service
is this true?

i don't care if this is a bad idea or shouldn't be done. i just want to know the code if can it be done so can someone please help?

Comment: "you can't interact with a service" - Broadly, yes. You could set up your service to run on the interactive session I think but I don't know if it's easy to set up the icon from that. And there may be more than one desktop session anyway. The best thing to do would be to write a separate small app for the notification bar that will start and stop the service for you. I think there's one bundled with Apache HTTPD - Apache Service Monitor - and the sources for that will probably be available.

Comment: so i can't just add some code to the existing program?

Comment: I thought you could, but [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683502.aspx) says this isn't allowed from Vista onwards but I may be wrong. In case you end up writing a separate tray app to control the service, here's the Apache code you  could start from: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/support/win32/

Comment: You could also add command-line switches to the program to start/stop the service and use these switches in the tray-icon

Comment: do you have any sample code to do that?

Comment: Not directly, there are a lot of sample code for tray icon projects (see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/74/Adding-Icons-to-the-System-Tray and also the "Related Articles" on the right.

Comment: so by using command-line switches i don't have to add a UI for the service?

Comment: that's right -- you could either use two new command-line switches in the service so that it starts/stops itself or you could start/stop the service from the icon tray program itself

Comment: i want the icon to be able to start/stop the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a "**Please avoid extended discussions in comments**" message, so I'm proposing this answer.

Write a icon tray application; [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/74/Adding-Icons-to-the-System-Tray) gives an example of how to do this (also see the "Related Articles" on the right of the article).

When you (right-) click on the tray icon, the icon tray application should determine if the service is already running; if yes, pop up a menu item to stop the service, otherwise pop up a menu item to start the service.

Answers to this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126443/programmatically-restart-a-windows-service) has pointers to how you can manage services using the Windows API.

Comment: so i need to create a separate application? i can't put the code into the program i'm using?

Comment: It is possible to add the tray icon functionality into the service with something like a new "-tray" command-line switch, but that would make the project extremely complex because you will have two different functionalities (service and tray-icon applications) controlled by different command-line switches -- I personally would not recommend it!

Comment: i understand that its not recommended but i really don't want to have 2 separate programs. all i want is when the service in installed and running an icon will appear with the option start and stop. will it really be that complex to do this?

Comment: Yes, because the tray-icon application needs windows and message loops, your service is just a Win32 Console Application -- you could add the tray-icon application as a new project under the same solution, though

Comment: I'm not familiar with that code, but if you're confident you can hack it, go ahead!

Comment: You can't do this. [Session 0 Isolation](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/10/01/session-0-isolation.aspx)